# Have window activate previous window on activation?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a program that runs over the top of the screen, I couldn't figure out how to allow clicks to the window behind it, so I have decided it's easier to just reactivate the previous window if its accidentally activated. It is not possible to tab into, the only way to activate it is to click the text on it.

So, I'm asking, is it possible to find the window activated just before my program is activated? I would prefer not to do a check every couple seconds or so for the currently active window.

Comment: You could hook into hit testing and make it appear transparent.

Comment: From what i found, hitTest doesn't let you click through if the thing behind it is not your wpf

Answer (score 0):

You can add `this.BringToFront();` after `InitializeComponent();` in the form constructor.

This will bring the form's window to the front.

Comment: I'n looking for pretty much the opposite of that, but to send the previously active window to the front.

Comment: @Inferna, oh apologies for misunderstanding you.
Perhaps if you send a reference of the previous window to the next window you could call it to the front by referencing it from the second window?